# Unity UWP load image bytes is missing color channels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, texture2d, windows-mixed-reality

I´m loading an image bytes and trying to apply it in a `Texture2D`.

*Don't worry about async/await/thread problems...*

UWP code:

```
StorageFile storageFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// get image size
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType random = storageFile.OpenReadAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
BitmapFrame bitmapFrame = decoder.GetFrameAsync(0).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
PixelDataProvider pixelData = bitmapFrame.GetPixelDataAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

return new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"bytes", pixelData.DetachPixelData()},
    {"width", (int) decoder.PixelWidth},
    {"height", (int) decoder.PixelHeight}
};
```

Unity code:

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(textureSizeStruct.width, textureSizeStruct.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

texture.LoadRawTextureData(textureBytes);
texture.Apply();
```

This is how the images show up...

Original:
[image]

In the app (sorry for the big white square):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP side get the pixels from decoder with the right params is needed. Follow below the solution:

```
StorageFile storageFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType random = storageFile.OpenReadAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// here is the catch
PixelDataProvider pixelData = decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
    BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, // <--- you must to get the pixels like this
    BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
    new BitmapTransform(),
    ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation,
    ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage // <--- you must to set this too
).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image channels are not missing, they are simply in a **different order**.

Check the docs of [Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html):

> Passed data should be of required size to fill the whole texture according to its width, height, **data format** and mipmapCount; otherwise a UnityException is thrown.

**Solution:**

Pass `TextureFormat.BGRA32` instead to your `Texture2D` constructor.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I found that was not the loading in Unity but in UWP, I will post the answer in a few minutes...